# jqplot Bar Charts ignores my floating numbers. How to fix them?

Tags: jqplot

I'm trying to generate a bar chart with jqplot. All of my values are floating numbers as below:

```
var s1 = [17.1, 18.2];
var s2 = [50.2, 53];
var s3 = [93.9, 93];
var s4 = [34.1, 34];
```

But it's rounding them to integers.

Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JkBKs/

How can I fix this?

Comment: yaxis:
    {
        tickOptions:
        {
            formatString: '%.2f'
        }
    }

Adding a yaxis formatting like above fixed it.

Answer (score 10):

try this,it works

```
        axes:
        {
            xaxis:{
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            },
            yaxis: {
                    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer, 
                    min: 0 ,
                    tickOptions: {
                                  formatString: '%.1f'
                                } 

                   }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

please see the ‘formatString’ content

```
seriesDefaults: {
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                // Show point labels to the right ('e'ast) of each bar.
                // edgeTolerance of -15 allows labels flow outside the grid
                // up to 15 pixels.  If they flow out more than that, they
                // will be hidden.
                pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15, formatString: '%.1f' },
                // Rotate the bar shadow as if bar is lit from top right.
                shadowAngle: 135,
                // Here's where we tell the chart it is oriented horizontally.
                rendererOptions: {
                    barDirection: 'horizontal'
                }
            },
            axes: {
                yaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                }
            }
```